# Bypass default view, Kohana

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

I want to return a view, however Kohana forces it through the default view, which I don't want. How do I temporary disable the default view?

Comment: What "default view"? Are you talking about the template controller?

Answer (score 1):

As zombor comments, if you are really talking about the template controller, you can disable its rendering by putting this line in your controller:

```
$this->auto_render = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function action_index()
    {
        $user_view = $this->getUserView();

        $this->request->response = View::factory('templates/main',$user_view);
    }
public function getUserView($user_details)
    {
        $user_view['list_page'] = View::factory('templates/usermgt')
                        ->bind('user_detail','data')
                        ->bind('msg','test');
        return $user_view;
    }
```

where getUserView() returns the view page, to action index.
hope it matches ur requirement